# Server reconnection using RxJS and angular 2 HTTP service

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http

What is the best way to handle a server reconnection using RxJS and Angular 2?

This is what I have so far:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class ConnectionService {

  // Stores the current status of the connection, false = not connected
  serviceOnline: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false)

  constructor(
    private http: Http
  ) {
    this.serviceOnline.asObservable().subscribe((online) => {
      console.log("Service online: " + JSON.stringify(online))
    })
    setTimeout( () => this.setServiceOffline(), 2000 );
  }

  setServiceOffline() {
    console.log("Setting service offline");
    this.serviceOnline.next(false);
    this.testConnection().delay(2000).repeat().takeUntil(this.serviceOnline).subscribe();
  }

  testConnection(): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log("Testing connection");
    return new Observable(observer => {
      this.http.get(`http://endpoint/ping`)
        .timeout(5000)
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error))
        .subscribe(() => {
          console.log("Connection successful");
          if(this.serviceOnline.getValue() == false)
            this.serviceOnline.next(true);
          observer.next(true);
          observer.complete();
        }, (error) => {
          console.log("Connection failed");
          if(this.serviceOnline.getValue() == true)
            this.serviceOnline.next(false);
          observer.next(false);
          observer.complete();
        });
    })
  }
}
```

Result in the console:

```
Service online: false
Setting service offline
Service online: false
Testing connection
Connection failed
```

If I replace this line..

```
this.testConnection().delay(2000).repeat().takeUntil(this.serviceOnline).subscribe();
```

with

```
this.testConnection().delay(2000).repeat().take(5).subscribe();
```

I do get the repeats:

```
Service online: false
Setting service offline
Service online: false
Testing connection
Connection failed
Connection failed
Connection failed
Connection failed
Connection failed
```

From the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeUntil):

> **public takeUntil(notifier: Observable): Observable**
>
> Emits the values emitted by the source Observable until a notifier
>   Observable emits a value.

The serviceOnline BehaviorSubject is only updated if there is a change in the server status. After this line...

```
this.serviceOnline.next(false);
```

...serviceOnline only emits another value when the http service has returned a successful response and if the current online status is false (disconnected):

```
if(this.serviceOnline.getValue() == false)
   this.serviceOnline.next(true);
```

So takeUntil should work. What am I misunderstanding/missing here?

I am new to RxJS - any other pointers on improving the implementation in this code would also be greatly appreciated...

Here is a Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/WUKxH6nFxc8LMKcxDPql?p=info

RxJS version 5.4. Angular version 4.

---

Returning serviceOnline as observable doesn't fix the issue:
    this.testConnection().delay(2000).repeat().takeUntil(this.serviceOnline.asObservable()).subscribe();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem occurs because `this.serviceOnline` always emits the last value when subscribed to, as it is an instance of `BehaviorSubject`. When you pass it to the `takeUntil` operator as a notifier observable, `takeUntil` subscribes to it and immediately receives a notification which leads to immediate completion of the resulting observable. Note that it doesn't matter whether the notifier observable emits `true` or `false`, `takeUntil` completes whenever it receives any value.

Try `.takeUntil(this.serviceOnline.filter(online => online === true))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm Have you tried doing this?:

```
this.testConnection().delay(2000).repeat().takeUntil(this.serviceOnline.asObservable()).subscribe();
```

Comment: Yeah, I also tried that. I'll add that to the question. Thanks

Comment: Hmm so, I recommend you to try debug your serviceOnline, something like this:

`constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.serviceOnline.asObservable().subscribe(notification => {
      console.log(notification)
    })
  }`

Comment: Yes, I also wondered if serviceOnline was immediately emitting a value and causing takeUntil to fire before repeating the testConnection observable, but it doesn't. A false value is emitted after the 'this.serviceOnline.next(false)' call and never again unless a successful http request is made. In that case it should just repeat, as it does when using Take (which gives limited repeats). Weird huh?

Comment: Maybe first subscribe then send an event? If i get it right.
`setServiceOffline() {
 this.testConnection().delay(2000).repeat().takeUntil(this.serviceOnline).subscribe();
    this.serviceOnline.next(false);
  }`

Comment: I've updated the answer with some console outputs. So the interesting thing is that 1 call to testConnection is getting through when using takeUntil...

Comment: @lufin, in your example `takeUntil` does not affect the internal subscription (`this.http.get(...).subscribe(...)`), that's why you see a single "Connection failed" in the log. Try returning the subscription so that `takeUntil` could unsubscribe from it: `new Observable(observer => { return this.http.get(...).subscribe(...) })`. The message should disappear from the log as `takeUntil` would unsubscribe before `this.http.get(...).timeout(...)` would produce an error.